# Phonegap / Cordova delete app data / files / everything ON UPDATE

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap

How to delete the app data / local storage / on app update .

I've tried a couple of written plugins and didn't managed to clear the old version phonegap app data when i'm installing the new version, because most of them are doing/calling the plugin process (that deletes the cache) on the app javascript file that never gets to execute , because all the static files are not being deleted & updated with the files from the new app version , app.js file , index.html , app.css are not being updated but loaded from cache instead.

What can i do to delete the old version app data ON UPDATE ??